# How should I force an element to remain fixed with parallax scrolling?

Tags: javascript, jquery, parallax

Abridged Codepen below. I'm trying to model a page after [this BBC article](http://www.bbc.com/news/special/2014/newsspec_7617/index.html#scrollmation-two-column-917) from way back, but I can't seem to get my image to go to position fixed based off scrolling.

I'm thinking that if I can get the element to be position: fixed then I can swap out the images with js

I can't seem to get my yPosition var to pass through my scroll function though
http://codepen.io/spkellydev/pen/aWzwdQ?editors=1111

Here's the fuller codepen of the project, I just can't seem to get this js to work for me. Any tips?

here's my JS

```
var yPosition = document.getElementById("scrollLock").offsetTop;



window.onscroll = function(){ // scrolling fires this function      
console.log(yPosition);
    var myElement = document.getElementById("scrollLock"); // for cleaner code

    // compare original y position of element to y position of page
  console.log('it is scrolled at');
    if( yPosition < window.pageYOffset ){ 

        // snap element to the top by changing css values of element
        myElement.addClass('addScrollLockImg'); 
        console.log('it worked');
     } else {          

        // re-position to original flow of content
       myElement.removeClass('addScrollLockImg');
       console.log('it passed');
    }               
}
```

Comment: Have you not made a mistake with `myElement.addClass('addScrollLockImg'); `? It's a Jquery function and it seems that myElement is not a Jquery object since you get it with `document.getElementById("scrollLock");`. Maybe do `myElement = $(myElement);`

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using position: sticky ?

This doesn't directly answer your question but will produce exactly what you are looking for.  [Sticky is not fully supported though](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky).

```
position: -webkit-sticky
position: sticky
top: 20px /* Distance from top of screen when 'stuck' */
```

This is all you need and it will keep it's place on the screen where the parent element allows.  As in it will not move outside of it's parent element.

[Your CodePen edited](http://codepen.io/BadMoodTaylor/pen/WjbJYW)  (I may have messed up some of your CSS)

Comment: I decided to go with the position: sticky even though the browser support is pretty bad. One day I'll go through and make it proper. Thanks for the tip